# Dynamic field names for active record objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i have this code where i get the field name dynamically .

```
field_name = #code to get field name as string
```

im then then looping through an array of activer record objects

```
results. each do |record| 
   puts "#{record.field_name}"
end
```

how do i evaluate that puts statement in ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Ruby way: `record.send(field_name)`

Another way with ActiveRecord: `record[field_name]`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send)

```
results.each do |record| 
  puts "#{record.send(field_name)}"
end
```